# Which Datatype to use for decimals?

Tags: oracle10g

Which datatype can be used to store numbers within between `0.0000001` and `1000`?

I tried using number(10) for the data - `0.01124.` But it stored it as `'0`.

Comment: It's all documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref80

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:Is there a way to change Number(10) to Number(10,5).Is it gonna work for older values.????Please reply

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#CJAHHIBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store this  at least as `number(11,7)`. old values will be preserved but they will not recover any lost precision due to you using (10) in the first place. i.e. `0.01124` that became `0` will still be `0` after you alter the column, as that precision was lost when you shoved the data into a number(10,0) field.

```
alter table foo modify(your_col number(x,y));
```

however, if your table is already number(10), then the MINIMUM that will work now to have a precision of 7 is :

```
alter table foo modify(your_col number(17,7));
```

to have say (11,7) will necessitate the old column having no data in it at all.